# MVC 5.1 Should I Install Bootstrap for MVC 5.1

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, visual-studio-2013, asp.net-mvc-5.1

I installed VS 2013 Express for Web and started to create MVC 5 project.

In MVC 5, Bootstrap is applied by default (I see in package folder there is bootstrap 3.0.0) and I updated to MVC 5.1 in order to get bootstrap compatibility (I can apply css for @Html.EditorFor only in MVC 5.1 so that i decided to update the MVC 5 to MVC 5.1).

There is Bootstrap for MVC 5.1 package, but if by default bootstrap 3.0.0 is already applied when we first create ASP.NET MVC 5 project, should I install Bootstrap for MVC 5.1 package? why? what are the advantages by installing this package?

Answer (score 0):

That package has a reference to Bootstrap 3.1.1, so it will upgrade your Bootstrap files to version 3.1.1. Other than that, there is no difference to the previous package version.

See http://www.nuget.org/packages/Twitter.Bootstrap.MVC/ for details.

Comment: I try to install Twitter.Bootstrap.MVC version 2.1.6 (using VS 2013 Update 1) but for example when I entered create paged, textbox didn't automatically apply boostrap css. This is different when I installed Twitter.Bootstrap.MVC version 1.1.7 (using VS 2012), it's automatically applied css on textbox. So that's why I asked this question

Comment: Check your App_Code/BundleConfig.cs and verify that the paths to the bootstrap files are correct. Also check your Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml so it has references to the bundles.